# How can I decorate latex documents like this one?

Tags: titles, templates, decorations, text-decorations, section-titles

I have very little knowledge of latex.
I use overleaf for writing documents.
recently, I saw a very nicely decorated template in overleaf, and here it is
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/schwangerschaftstagebuch-download-vorlage-zum-eintragen-am-rechner/mfgyygkryckx

I used this template to write a document and it was very nice. It has decorations by green leaves, nice decoration of margins, nice design after a section closing, nice title page, also nice calligraphies, nice letters in each section headings.

How can I design such documents on my own?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you just keep using the document class (and maybe some LaTeX packages too) and keep using the same commands to create the decorations in question?

Comment: From my experience, the first step is to grasp basic LaTeX skills and use maybe a bunch of templates like this. We are then curious about how they are achieved by looking into their sources (`cls` or `sty`). Gradually we are capable of writing elegant templates ourselves and then improving it. I think a good start is the template [ElegantBook](https://github.com/ElegantLaTeX/ElegantBook).

Answer (score 1):

if you open the template, e.g. also in an external tool like MikTex, you see a regular structure. So if you forget about the leafs and ornaments for a moment you can come up with a document structure like this as well, soon yourself.

There are some special things. As I don't have an overleaf account, I didn't find an alternative to access the content of the various files that are loaded via `\input` : Inhalt/xy - some text, DASTsec, DASTmeta, DASTmacros and DASTpackages.

The "Inhalt"-Files will probably not come with surprises. DASTmacros will define many newcommands, which shall make entering text in certain formats easy. The \callitrue and \audiotrue have their place here, as well.

So as a process or procedure, you could do stepwise evolvement and refinement, e.g. like this:

- create a structure of chapters etc.
- move these to external files and replace by \input-statements
- apply ornaments (see e.g. ctan.org , or search here)
- simplify such code by creating \newcommand macros
- put those macros in an external file, use \input to load it
- and so on

Unfortunately this template is quite complex in the sense of requiring quite some knowledge to do it. However, with 1 or 2 good books on Latex introduction and some patience you can do it step by step. But it will take more "than a weekend" ;-)

Finally, the overleaf template for reference - not too much of "black magic":

```
\newif\iftablet    %\tablettrue % format for tablets/screen
\newif\ifcalli     \callitrue  % calligraphy for letters
\newif\ifaudio     \audiotrue  % link for audio files


\iftablet
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\else
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}

\fi

\title{Vorlage Schwangerschaftstagebuch}

\input{DASTpackages} % <= content would be interesting to know
\input{DASTmacros} % <= same
\input{DASTmeta} % <= same

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\pagestyle{empty}
%test\newpage
\input{titelpage}\iftablet \newpage \else \cleardoublepage \fi

\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents \iftablet \newpage \else \cleardoublepage \fi 
% XXX Wenn du kein Inhaltsverzeichnis haben möchtest, kannst du diese Zeile ab \tableofcontents löschen.

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{DASTsec} % <= same

% XXX Setze vor die Teile, die nicht im PDF auftauchen sollen, ein %. Dadurch wird die ganze Zeile blau. Der Code wird nicht mehr gelesen.
\input{Inhalt/01- Einleitung}
\input{Inhalt/02- Vorgeschichte}
\input{Inhalt/03- mehr Vorgeschichte}
\input{Inhalt/04- 1. Schwangerschaftsmonat}
 \input{Inhalt/05- 2. Schwangerschaftsmonat}
 \input{Inhalt/06- 3.Schwangerschaftsmonat}
 \input{Inhalt/07- 4.Schwangerschaftsmonat}
 \input{Inhalt/08- 5. Schwangerschaftsmonat}
 \input{Inhalt/09- 6. Schwangerschaftsmonat}
 \input{Inhalt/10- 7. Schwangerschaftsmonat}
 \input{Inhalt/11- 8.Schwangerschaftsmonat}
 \input{Inhalt/12- 9.Schwangerschaftsmonat}
 \input{Inhalt/13- 10.Schwangerschaftsmonat}
 \input{Inhalt/14- Die Geburt}
 \input{Inhalt/15- Das Wochenbett}

\end{document}
```